# how to write a mysql query based on the output?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My **table** should be like this:

```
slno      sheetno   time_stamp
1         101       2018-05-27 11:16:58 
2         103       2018-05-27 11:20:18 
3         102       2018-05-27 11:24:39 
4         105       2018-05-27 11:27:44 
5         106       2018-05-27 11:34:03 
6         107       2018-05-27 11:51:32 
7         108       2018-05-27 12:41:34 
8         109       2018-05-27 12:48:13 
9         110       2018-05-27 12:52:40 
10        111       2018-05-27 13:18:59 
11        112       2018-05-27 14:13:07 
12        113       2018-05-27 14:18:04 
13        114       2018-05-27 14:21:12 
14        115       2018-05-27 14:54:01 
15        117       2018-05-27 14:55:14 
16        118       2018-05-27 14:57:31 
17        119       2018-05-27 15:05:30 
18        120       2018-05-27 15:30:44 
19        121       2018-05-27 15:46:38 
20        122       2018-05-27 16:02:16 
21        123       2018-05-28 11:32:10 
22        124       2018-05-28 11:38:18 
23        125       2018-05-28 11:49:45 
24        126       2018-05-28 11:52:09 
25        127       2018-05-28 12:21:00 
26        128       2018-05-28 12:24:33 
27        129       2018-05-28 13:04:56 
28        130       2018-05-28 14:10:07 
29        140       2018-05-28 14:18:47 
30        141       2018-05-28 14:22:09 
31        142       2018-05-28 14:28:04 
32        143       2018-05-28 14:37:53 
33        144       2018-05-28 15:06:27 
34        145       2018-05-28 15:33:05 
35        146       2018-05-28 15:35:44 
36        147       2018-05-28 15:53:41 
37        148       2018-05-28 16:13:16 
38        149       2018-05-28 16:27:51 
39        150       2018-05-28 16:38:54 
40        151       2018-05-28 16:44:54
```

My **output** should be like this:

```
From           To            Total No of days   FN   AN
27-05-2018     28-05-2018    2                  2    2
```

This is my **query**:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(MIN(time_stamp), '%Y-%m-%d') AS min,
    DATE_FORMAT(MAX(time_stamp), '%Y-%m-%d') AS max,
    COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(time_stamp)) AS cnt,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN  TIME(time_stamp) < '12:00:00' THEN 1 END) AS FN,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TIME(time_stamp) >= '12:00:00' THEN 1 END) AS AN 
FROM master_tab;
```

The output of 'FN' ,'AN' should be grouped. How to solve this?
I've tried to put `DISTINCT` in front of case it shows i value.

Comment: In what way did it fail? Any error messages?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') end as FN, count(case when time(time_stamp) between '12:00:00' and '24:00:00')' at line 2

Comment: You _still_ haven't shown us the actual output you expect from this larger data set.  The output you do show does not match up with the input.  Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be on the right track:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(MIN(time_stamp), '%Y-%m-%d') AS min,
    DATE_FORMAT(MAX(time_stamp), '%Y-%m-%d') AS max,
    COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(time_stamp)) AS cnt,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TIME(time_stamp) < '12:00:00' THEN 1 END) AS FN,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TIME(time_stamp) >= '12:00:00' THEN 1 END) AS VA
FROM master_tab;
```

[image]

### Demo

Notes:

- To select the min/max dates, there is no sense in doing an extra cast to date, because `DATE_FORMAT` will already these values as dates only.
- Same is true for the distinct date count; note that `DISTINCT` is *not* a function in MySQL, but rather a keyword
- The conditional counts for `FN` (morning) and `VA` (evening) times count the number 1 when there is a match, and count `NULL` otherwise.  Note that `NULL` is ignored by `COUNT`, so we only tally matching records.  The `ELSE` condition, which is omitted, defaults to `NULL`.

Comment: how FN,Va to be grouped? per day either AN or FN ,but this query returns many 'AN' and 'FN'

Comment: You are asking for a different query than what your question describes.  Is there some reason why you are changing your question now?

Comment: see my post i display my time_stamp output

Comment: your query is working perfectly, but i want those 'AN, 'FN' should be grouped or distinct values

Comment: Edit your question and show exact input and output.  Then, I can try to change my answer.  Without those changes, this answer will stay as is.

Comment: `Pls solve` : Stack Overflow isn't a free homework service

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(MIN(time_stamp), '%Y-%m-%d') AS min,
    DATE_FORMAT(MAX(time_stamp), '%Y-%m-%d') AS max,
    COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(time_stamp)) AS cnt,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(DATE(time_stamp),(CASE WHEN TIME(time_stamp) < '12:00:00' THEN 1 END))) AS FN,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(DATE(time_stamp),(CASE WHEN TIME(time_stamp) >= '12:00:00' THEN 1 END))) AS VA
FROM master_tab;
```

And the output

```
min         max         cnt FN  VA
2018-05-27  2018-05-28  2   2   2
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/UHONM27038)**

Comment: superji . my expected output came. thanks to Tim and you.

Comment: one more doubt. i want to multiply those FN & AN values *250 .

Comment: yes you can do 
COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(DATE(time_stamp),(CASE WHEN TIME(time_stamp) < '12:00:00' THEN 1 END))) *250  AS FN,